# How much diskspace does a database take?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for hosting at the moment for a wiki and wordpress site. 
Looking around it looks like most hosts offer a number of databases with a max size of 1GB.

With this seeming to be the norm, would 1GB be enough to support most sites needs? What are common database sizes?

I am assuming that my site falls in to the 'most sites' category.

The wiki is relatively small, and contains around 800-1000 pages at the most. The wordpress would be updated multiple times per month with new articles.

Comment: This is way too vague. "a complex game with many strategies, classes, and card types etc" could mean _anything_.

Comment: depends upon u requirement.. big wiki can be of 10 gb too.

Comment: The wiki would be roughly the size of the hearthstone.wikia.com .I'm not really sure how to work that size out.

Comment: I've edited my question to be a little less broad. Is it OK now?

Comment: Made the title a bit more broad so it can attrqact a less specific type of visitors

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the amount of text content. Your description isn't suffice to say how much you need, but I'm willing to guess that 1GB is plenty. Images and script and such are not stored in a database.

If you have a huge amount of pages with huge amount of text, then you'll need a larger database than a site with a few news articles on it.

#### Some examples:

A webshop with 5000+ products, plenty categories and brands, few thousand user accounts, multiple categories per product, storing a lot of stats et cetera: **~500MB**.

A more common 'local' serving webshop, couple hundred items, one brand and one category per product, hew hundred users : **~100MB**

An order placement system with 30.000 users and 50.000 orders: **~75MB**.

A fairly standard site (normal amount of users, about 75 pages): **~50MB**

Small website (a few pages in a CMS): **<1MB**

Comment: Great! So most sites would easily stay within the size limit?
I was worried because I thought images were stored there, but now I look it is just their locations.

Comment: Unless your site suddenly gets mega popular and mega big, you won't have anything to worry, and by the time you do, your skills should've increased sufficiently to assess the new situation.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Not sure why I got down votes though.

Comment: BEcause the first version of your question was bad. If this answer is what you needed, please mark as solution :)